# plotting data from a hid usb device with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I use pywinusb to get data from a human interface device. I register a handler, to get the values.

```
def sample_handler(data):
   print("Raw data: {0}".format(data))
...
device.set_raw_data_handler(sample_handler)
```

Instead of printing the data I'd like to plot them using matplotlib. How can I transfer the data from this handler to the funtion of matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation?

Comment: What are you stuck on? Saving the data? Plotting the data? Animating it? Do you want it to animate live?

Comment: I want to animate the data live.

Comment: So what part are you unable to do? [Does this help?](http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/strip_chart_demo.html)

Comment: In your example the emitter is called every 10 ms by a matplotlib thread. In my case I have the sample_handler, which is called by the pyusb thread. Somehow I have to sync the two.

Comment: Is my answer on the right track?

Comment: I guess yes. I am not so familiar with threading, queues etc. When calling plt.show() it blocks.

Comment: The `data.get` will block when waiting for data to be given by `device`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure what you need, but maybe something like:

```
import queue
from matplotlib import animation

data = queue.Queue()

device.set_raw_data_handler(data.put)
animation.FuncAnimation(iter(data.get, ...), OTHER ARGUMENTS)
```

This just passes all the data straight from the `device` to the `animation`.